# Pattern for mapping and scanning at the same time

Tags: rxjs

Let's say I have an observable of low-level actions (e.g., mousemove events), and I'd like to simultaneously scan over them to build a state, as well as emit an Observable of higher-level actions (e.g., mouse gestures). If I just use scan(), the reducer can only return the state, so that's no good. If I just use map() on the low level actions, the projection function won't have access to the state, so that won't work.

I can work around it by first scan()ing and then zipping that back with the original action stream, or by having the state include the last high-level action, and then using map() to isolate the high-level actions from the state, but those both feel kinda gross. This seems like a relatively simple idea, so is there a general pattern people follow?

*(To be clear, I'm not actually working with mouse gestures, so I can't use short cuts like only looking at small windows of the past: I really do want the full state.)*

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could intersperse some code in your description, but one comment I can make  -  `the reducer can only return the state`. The reducer can return an object which has both accumulator (as a property) and prior events (as an array property). If you post some code and desired results, can make some more concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I just did is `scan` to create tuples of current input and state.  Then you can `map` away the state once you no longer need it.

E.g. this wraps it all up in an operator (TypeScript; remove types if you insist on JavaScript):

```
export type FnWithState<F, S, T> = (from: F, state: S) => [T, S];

export function mapWithState<F, S, T>(fn: FnWithState<F, S, T>, initialState: S)
: OperatorFunction<F, T> {
  return (in$: Rx.Observable<F>) =>
    in$.pipe(scan(([_out, state]: [T, S], from: F) => fn(from, state),
                  [{} as T, initialState]),
             map(([out, _state]) => out));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
type WordHist = immutable.Map<string, number>;

function emitEveryThird(word: string, hist: WordHist): [string | null, WordHist] {
  const newHist = hist.update(word, (n = 0) => n + 1);
  return [newHist.get(word)! % 3 === 0 ? word : null, newHist];
}

const in$ = Rx.Observable.from(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b']);

const actual: string[] = [];
await in$.pipe(mapWithState(emitEveryThird, immutable.Map()))
  .subscribe((w) => w && actual.push(w));

t.deepEqual(['a', 'a', 'b'], actual);
```